# How to created a shared library (dylib) using automake that JNI/JNA can use?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, jna, automake, libtool

How do I convince LibTools to generate a library identical to what gcc does automatically?

This works if I do things explicitly:

```
gcc -o libclique.dylib -shared disc.c  phylip.c Slist.c  clique.c
cp libclique.dylib [JavaTestDir]/libclique.dylib
```

But if I do:

```
Makefile libclique.la (which is what automake generates)
cp .libs/libclique.1.dylib [JavaTestDir]/libclique.dylib
```

Java finds the library but can't find the entry point.

I read the "How to create a shared library (.so) in an automake script?" thread and it helped a lot. I  got the dylib created with a -shared flag (according to the generated Makefile). But when I try to use it from Java Native Access I get a "symbol not found" error.

Looking at the `libclique.la` that is generated by Makefile it doesn't seem to have any critical information in it, just looks to be link overloads and moving things around for the convenience of subsequent C/C++ compiler steps (which I don't have), so I would expect `libclique.1.dylib` to be a functioning dynamic library.

I'm guessing that is where I'm going wrong, but, given that JNA links directly to a dylib and is not compiled with it (per the example in the discussion cited above), it seems all the subsequent compilation steps described in the LibTools manual are moot.

Note: I'm testing on a Mac, but I'm going to have to do this on Windows and Linux machines also, which is why I'm trying to put this into Automake.

Note2: I'm using Eclipse for my Java development and, yes, I did import the dylib.

Thanks

Comment: What does `nm` tell you about the symbols in the .dylib?  Is the symbol you're looking for actually in the displayed list?

Comment: Excellent question, and dead on. The dylib created by LibTools is a dyld_stub_binder, not a true dylib. Which is puzzling, because the above mentioned article claims that a functional .so file was created. Perhaps the problem is I need only a dylib, I don't need to compile an executable (I can't in fact, because Java is not compiled and JNA is a freestanding jar file). So the question becomes, how do I convert what LibTools outputs to a free standing dylib such as gcc creates. Google is not being helpful.

Comment: @Oz123 Did a bit more testing, modifying something in one of the library parts and doing a make. Got the following (sorry about the wrap):make all-am
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -Wall -Wfatal-errors -DNDEBUG -O3 -MT clique.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/clique.Tpo -c -o clique.o clique.c
mv -f .deps/clique.Tpo .deps/clique.Po /bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -DNDEBUG -O3     -o clique phylip.o Slist.o dumptree.o clique.o disc.o  -lm 
libtool: link: gcc -Wall -Wfatal-errors -DNDEBUG -O3 -o clique phylip.o Slist.o dumptree.o clique.o disc.o  -lm Which all looks good .

Comment: @technomage Added a couple comments, but forgot to tag them to you.

Comment: Well, I'm gobsmacked! By adding LibTools, my executable (clique) now is also a dylib and can be accessed directly by JNA. Even the LibTool manual doesn't mention that. Problem solved though in a very unexpected way. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You should be [building a plugin](https://autotools.io/libtool/plugins.html) and in particular pass

```
libclique_la_LDFLAGS = -avoid-version -module -shared -export-dynamic
```

This way you tell libtool you want a dynamically loadable module rather than a shared library (which for ELF are the same thing, but for Mach-O are not.)